# Read json output into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: json, pandas

How do I put the following json output into a pandas dataframe?

```
[{'currency': '1ST', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': '8BT', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'ADX', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AE', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AEON', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AIR', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AMB', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AMM', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AMP', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}]
```

I've tried the following but only receive the following error:

Code

```
balances = pd.read_json(data)
```

Error

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'method'>
```

Edit -  How I get the data:

```
def get_account_balance(self):
    """Get main balance."""
    return self.session.get("https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/account/balance").json()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns')
```

Source: https://github.com/vi3k6i5/pandas_basics/blob/master/1_a_create_a_dataframe_from_dictonary.ipynb

Answer (score 4):

IIUC assuming you have a dictionary:

```
In [231]: d = [{'currency': 'ZRX', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'ZSC', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}]

In [235]: pd.DataFrame(d)
Out[235]:
  available currency reserved
0         0      ZRX        0
1         0      ZSC        0
```

---

If it's a string (broken JSON, as JSON must have double quotes instead of single quotes):

```
import json

In [238]: s = """
     ...: [{'currency': 'ZRX', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'ZSC', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}]
     ...: """

In [239]: d = json.loads(s.replace("'", '"'))

In [240]: pd.DataFrame(d)
Out[240]:
  available currency reserved
0         0      ZRX        0
1         0      ZSC        0
```

Comment: I get the following error using your string approach: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'. See my edit above on how I get the data.

Comment: @alpenmilch411, please provide a small __reproducible__ sample data set, so that we could reproduce your issue

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what do you exactly mean with reproducible sample data set? See my edit above. @MaxU

Comment: @alpenmilch411, i mean that we need a data set which would help us to reproduce your error. When I try the data set from your question - both my solutions are working properly - whether it's a string or a dictionary...

Comment: Okay so my edit above solved the problem but I am guessing there is a better way to do this. @MaxU

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while importing a json file to a pandas dataframe. I've solved it by flattening the dictionaries and then importing them normally:

```
def get_values(lVals):
    res = []
    for val in lVals:
        if type(val) not in [list, set, tuple]:
            res.append(val)
        else:
            res.extend(get_values(val))
    return res

data = get_values(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference:

[Python how convert single quotes to double quotes to format as json string | user3850](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47659782/python-how-convert-single-quotes-to-double-quotes-to-format-as-json-string)

```
import json
import pandas as pd

json_data = [{'currency': '1ST', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': '8BT', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'ADX', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AE', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AEON', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AIR', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AMB', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AMM', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}, {'currency': 'AMP', 'available': '0', 'reserved': '0'}]

json_format = json.dumps(json_data)

json_df = pd.read_json(json_format)

json_df.head()
```